# Spring Boot - html table shows expired data

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, transactions

I do have Spring boot project, and I am using JPA.
One of my controllers returns a page 'myclass.html', with a table on it.

```
@Secured("ROLE_USER")
@Controller
public class UserController {

  @RequestMapping("/myClass")
  public String myClass(Model model) {

   model.addAttribute("students", studentService.findCurrentStudents());
   return "user/myclass";
  }

}
```

The studentService does 2 things (by calling 2 separate methods on the UserRepository):

- It updates the STUDENTS table to make some changes depending on the actual date.
- It returns back the STUDENTS table

Even the update is defined earlier, and then the list return, when I test it, the table contains the old data (the one before the update), and if I refresh the window, after the refresh it will then show the modified data finally.
 Do I need to encapsulate them into a single transaction to keep the order of the execution? If I must, how can I do it in the most simplest way?

I copy the actual part of the mentioned service:

```
    @Override
    public List<Student> findCurrentStudents() {

        studentRepository.updateByUserAndDate(currentUserId(), new Date());
        return studentRepository.findCurrentStudentsByUser(currentUserId());

    }
```

And the repository:

```
@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends CrudRepository<Student, Long> {

@Query(value="SELECT * FROM Students WHERE user_id = :currentUserId, nativeQuery = true)
List<Student> findCurrentStudentsByUser(@Param("userId") Integer currentUserId);

@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query(value="UPDATE Students SET last_review = :newDate WHERE user_id = :userId", nativeQuery = true)
void updateByUserAndDate(@Param("userId")Long id, @Param("newDate") Date date);
```

Comment: *Do I need to encapsulate them into a single transaction*: yes: every interaction with the database should be done in a transaction. Annotate your service, or your controller, with `@Transactional`. Not knowing the code of your repository doesn't help explaining the issue.

Comment: I have added the code of the repository. Unfortunately the @Transactional annotation did not solve the issue (I have added on the Service implementation at the top), but hopefully the code of the repository will explain it to you.

Comment: Have you tried disabling the cache in the developer tools of your browser?

Comment: Yes I have, unfortunately does not work.